# How to update multiple columns of given dataframe with new corresponding scraped data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

Following dataframe consists of two empty columns (Sales and Income), that should be updated with scraped data corresponding to the ticker column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'No.': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '5'}, 
    'Ticker': {0: 'AAPL', 1: 'MSFT', 2: 'TSLA', 3: 'FB', 4: 'BRK-B'}, 
    'Sales': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: ''}, 
    'Income': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: ''}, 
    'Company': {0: 'Apple Inc.', 1: 'Microsoft Corporation', 2: 'Tesla, Inc.', 3: 'Meta Platforms, Inc.', 4: 'Berkshire Hathaway Inc.'}, 
    'Sector': {0: 'Technology', 1: 'Technology', 2: 'Consumer Cyclical', 3: 'Communication Services', 4: 'Financial'}
    })
```

With additional code below I am able to pull in the Sales and Income information from the snapshot table, but only for one ticker and I do not know how to update the dataframe:

**Additional Code**

```
    ticker = (df.iloc[0,1])
    #---------- Pulling the data from chosen stock ticker ----------#
    
    url = ('https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=' + ticker.upper())
    
    req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    table = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs = {"class":"snapshot-table2"} )
    df = table[0]
    
    print(f'{df[0][3]}: {df[1][3]}: {df[0][2]}: {df[1][2]}')
```

**Expected result:**

| No. | Ticker | Sales | Income | Company | Sector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAPL | 365.82B | 94.68B | Apple Inc. | Technology |
| 2 | MSFT | 176.25B | 67.88B | Microsoft Corporation | Technology |
| 3 | TSLA | 46.85B | 3.47B | Tesla, Inc. | Consumer Cyclical |
| 4 | FB | 112.33B | 40.30B | Meta Platforms, Inc. | Communication Services |
| 5 | BRK-B | 268.68B | - | Berkshire Hathaway Inc. | Financial |

Comment: Updated your question to show only the necessary information - just take a look. hope your next question structure will be more similar to this one. always provide your data frame so that others can easily reproduce it. Would be great - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to achieve?

Put your additional code into a def and use `zip()` in combination with `map()` to update your columns:

```
df['Sales'],df['Income'] = zip(*df['Ticker'].map(lambda x: get_ticker(x)))
```

#### Example

**Note:** *Ticker may can change (FB -> META) therefore always keep also an eye on the contents that are requested in the case of errors*

```
def get_ticker(ticker):
    #---------- Pulling the data from chosen stock ticker ----------#
    
    url = ('https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=' + ticker.upper())
    
    req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    table = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs = {"class":"snapshot-table2"} )
    df = table[0]
    return(df[1][3],df[1][2])


df['Sales'],df['Income'] = zip(*df['Ticker'].map(lambda x: get_ticker(x)))
```

#### Output

| No. | Ticker | Sales | Income | Company | Sector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAPL | 365.82B | 94.68B | Apple Inc. | Technology |
| 2 | MSFT | 176.25B | 67.88B | Microsoft Corporation | Technology |
| 3 | TSLA | 46.85B | 3.47B | Tesla, Inc. | Consumer Cyclical |
| 4 | FB | 112.33B | 40.30B | Meta Platforms, Inc. | Communication Services |
| 5 | BRK-B | 268.68B | - | Berkshire Hathaway Inc. | Financial |

Comment: Thanks you so much, it works amazing!!!

Comment: Incredibly, when I run the code on 6,235 symbols, it's 6 minutes slower than my previous method.  The old way, I exported the DF to excel and then ran a separate file of all the tickers, aapl, msft, amzn, etc. in VBA from the Pandas DF and then merged the 2 files also in VBA.  Any idea why this is slower?

Comment: Just to clarify, I ran a comma delimited list and put the 6,235 ticker symbols, aapl, msft, amzn, etc. in to 18 cells in Excel. So there are 400 symbols in each cell.

Comment: Good point! Each question should focus one issue only - this additional question is just predestined to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Would be great. - Just in case, you can collect the data in same with python and `merge()` the dataframes

Comment: Hi Hedgehog.  I went back to use this code you wrote and it no longer works.  Tried eveything I could think of but no luck.

Comment: Raider is now called Twix, otherwise nothing changes... Simple way to check `print(url,req)` in function and you will see what happens in the *metaverse* ;)

Comment: Very funny, thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't help myself with that through ball. I have included an appropriate reference to the context of example in my answer.

Comment: I don't think the errors I'm getting have anything to do with the ticker change from fb to meta if that's what you're saying. I'm getting a ton of errors I didn't used to get.

Comment: Cause there is some time ago and things may have changed This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus and inlcuding specific stack trace. Drop a link to new question and we will check it.

Comment: Ok Thanks,  Here is the link to the new question when you have time. 
 Thanks so much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551051/python-web-scraping-is-no-longer-working