# Python -Web scraping is no longer working

Tags: pandas, web-scraping

this code used to work beautifully 9 months ago. Now, it gives me a number of errors. The goal of the code is to first scrape about 50 columns of data from a table at Finviz.com. The code inserts 2 blank columns for Sales and Income which aren't in the first table and must come from a second Finviz table.

Code for Sales and Income

```
def get_ticker(ticker):
    #---------- Pulling the data from chosen stock ticker ----------#

    url = ('https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=' + ticker.upper())

    req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    table = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs = {"class":"snapshot-table2"} )
    df = table[0]
    return(df[1][3],df[1][2])


df['Sales'],df['Income'] = zip(*df['Ticker'].map(lambda x: get_ticker(x)))

print(df)
```

Partial Results from when the code worked.

[image: Partial Results from when it worked.]

Current Errors

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\Scripts\Script_Hedgehog14\Hedgehog14.py", line 48, in <module>
        df['Sales'],df['Income'] = zip(*df['Ticker'].map(lambda x: get_ticker(x)))
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packa

ges\pandas\core\series.py", line 4539, in map
        new_values = self._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 890, in _map_values
        new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2918, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\Scripts\Script_Hedgehog14\Hedgehog14.py", line 48, in <lambda>
        df['Sales'],df['Income'] = zip(*df['Ticker'].map(lambda x: get_ticker(x)))
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\Scripts\Script_Hedgehog14\Hedgehog14.py", line 43, in get_ticker
        table = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs = {"class":"snapshot-table2"} )
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1205, in read_html
        return _parse(
               ^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1006, in _parse
        raise retained
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 986, in _parse
        tables = p.parse_tables()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 262, in parse_tables
        tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\jkru0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 618, in _parse_tables
        raise ValueError("No tables found")
    ValueError: No tables found
```

Full Code

```
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import bs4
    import time
    import random
    
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    
    def testDf(version):
        url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&r={page}&f=all&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70&f=ind_stocksonly&o=-marketcap'
        
        page = 1
    
        screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features='lxml')
        pages = int(soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'screener-pages'})[-1].text)
    
        data = []
        for page in range(1, 20 * pages, 20):
            print(version, page)
            screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers).text
            tables = pd.read_html(screen)
            tables = tables[-2]
            tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
            tables = tables[1:]
            data.append(tables)
            time.sleep(random.random())
        return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
    
    
    df = testDf('152').copy()
    df.insert(2,'Sales',"")
    df.insert(3,'Income',"")
    
    # The newly converted dataframe is in the df variable
    
    def get_ticker(ticker):
        #---------- Pulling the data from chosen stock ticker ----------#
        
        url = ('https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=' + ticker.upper())
        
        req = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        table = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs = {"class":"snapshot-table2"} )
        df = table[0]
        return(df[1][3],df[1][2])
    
    
    df['Sales'],df['Income'] = zip(*df['Ticker'].map(lambda x: get_ticker(x)))
    
    print(df)
    
    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Gold.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    
    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    
    # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    
    header_format = workbook.add_format()
    header_format.set_font_name('Calibri')
    header_format.set_font_color('green')
    header_format.set_font_size(8)
    header_format.set_italic()
    header_format.set_underline()
    
    # Write the column headers with the defined format.
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
    
    writer.save()
```

Comment: There are a bunch of data providers who will provide an API for this. Yahoo Finance, for example, has a free API. Why bother with scraping?

Comment: Never was a fan of yahoo's information.

Comment: At first try to check the response before `pd.read_html()` like `req.status_code != 200: print(url,req)` so you will get an idea if something may be wrong with your request (changing tickers,...) or print the source as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70643842/14460824 . Could you provide a list of tickers?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are over 6,000 tickers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update `Uset-Agent` HTTP header:

```py
def get_ticker(ticker):
    # ---------- Pulling the data from chosen stock ticker ----------#

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0"
    }
    url = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" + ticker.upper()
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    table = pd.read_html(req.text, attrs={"class": "snapshot-table2"})
    df = table[0]
    return (df[1][3], df[1][2])


print(get_ticker("AAPL"))
```

Prints:

```
('394.33B', '99.80B')
```

Comment: I tried that but still get the same errors when I run the full code.  Thanks

Comment: @user3444610 Check the return HTML. You've probably got captcha page.

Comment: The script works flawlessly on my end.

Comment: Is the full code working for you?  I don't see how that's possible when I'm getting these errors?